# Formatting 'defaults domains' output on multiple lines

Tags: terminal, bash, defaults

Just a quick question here. I'm trying to format the output of the command:

```
defaults domains
```

so that it puts each domain on a new line, so I can use that parsed output in a different command.

I've tried:

```
defaults domains | sed 's/,/\n/g'
```

Which should take the output of default, find each comma, and replace with a new line correct? Instead it just removes the comma and keeps each item on the same line.

I thought, maybe it's something with the encoding of the dafaults command output, so I dumped to a file and tried parsing that, but no dice.

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OS X using the default BSD `sed` you can do it a few different ways, here's a couple ways.

```
defaults domains | sed 's/,/\
/g'
```

You'd press Enter after typing the backslash, no "n" and finish off with the `/g'` on the next line. This substitutes a literal newline.

This also works:

```
defaults domains | sed 's/,/\'$'\n/g'
```

Some of us install the GNU version of various command line programs such as this and your original `defaults domains | sed 's/,/\n/g'` would work just fine with GNU `sed`.

That all said, I have to say that since `tr` could do what you needed/wanted so easily it *was* the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in BSD varients you actually put a new line instead of the carriage return indicator, but I didn't get around to trying it before I got tr to work.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Not sure why sed didn't work the way I wanted it to, but I just used:

```
tr ',' '\n'
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: `tr` will work multiple times faster than using `sed`, if `tr` can do the task. Even chaining `tr` with `sed` will work faster than just using `sed`.

Comment: LOL! Never gotten a negative before. I thought it would be prudent to answer my own question, but maybe not?

Comment: I believe you were voted down because you didn't edit your original post with your solution.

Comment: @fd0, That is no excuse for down-voting and it is perfectly fine for the author of the OP to post as an answer to their own question, even if the solution is different then what was being asked about.  In any event I up-voted the question as it's a valid answer even though mine did address the `sed` issues encountered in the OP.  See:[Can I answer my own question?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @ user3439894 I did not down vote Chris. I do not appreciate your assumption,

Comment: fd0 I wasn't trying to say you were doing it, just that it was done. Sorry! I didn't mean to point fingers!

Comment: @fd0, I **did not** say **you** were the down-voter, I merely said "_That is no excuse for down-voting..._" as a general statement and nothing else!

Comment: Sorry I use several Stack Exchange sub communities and each one has different rules. Admittedly I don't read them very thoroughly, so the best practice here is to update the original answer, not add your own?

Comment: @Chris Gleason, The question asked is just that _the question asked_ regardless of what the answers or accepted answer become.  It is encouraged that if you come up with your own answer then post it as an answer.  This way it clearer to the readers what are the questions and the respective answers.